# God, I'm so bad with names

Tags: riddle

You know that guy who's got a wide, oval nose and huge buckteeth? The guy who's always wearing sunglasses, you know the one. What's his name again?

Comment: a rot13(ornire)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Oh, I know the guy you mean - his name is:

> **BOB**

What do you mean, "Why?" Have you never *seen* this guy? Well, maybe you have - just not from the right angle:

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Is this guy a

> Raccoon

You know that guy who's got a wide, oval nose

> [image: wide, oval nose]

and huge buckteeth?

> [image: huge buckteeth]

The guy who's always wearing sunglasses,

> [image: wearing sunglasses]

Answer (score 2):

Is he ?

> [Professor Frink (The Simpsons)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_Frink%20%20%20)

> [image]

Comment: Not sunglasses, but I laughed.